# PHP access object values dynamically by variable name

Tags: php, variables, object

I have this little snippet:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
// some other code

// works
$properties = $client->__soapCall($action, array(
    array(
        'Page' => $x
    )
));

// try to get access to values by var $action
$obj = $properties->$action->item;
```

This gives me an error. My intention was to use the script only once for multiple operations by getting different actions.

...but I have no idea how to solve this and I haven't found any helpful posts or articles.

`var_dump($properties)`:

```
object(stdClass)#84 (4) {
    ["PropertyGroups"]=>
        object(stdClass)#85 (1) {
            ["item"]=>
                array(73) {
                    [0]=>
                        object(stdClass)#86 (7) {
                            ["PropertyGroupID"]=>int(1)
                        }
                }
          }
  }
```

Comment: `This gives me an error.` We should guess it right?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Sorry. If `action = GetPropertyGroups`,
`Undefined property: stdClass::$GetPropertyGroups`

Comment: var_dump($properties)

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: I am currently using PHP 5.5.30 but it's possible to upgrade to 7.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script and this line

```
$obj = $properties->$action->item;
```

Are absolutely OK. But, as you pointed out in the comments,

> If action = GetPropertyGroups, Undefined property:
>   `stdClass::$GetPropertyGroups`

You have `PropertyGroups` property in `$properties`, **not `GetPropertyGroups`**.

You should check if the property you're looking for exists:

```
property_exists($properties, $action)
```

Comment: You are absolutly right. This was my mistake, I didn's see it. Thank you!